# GE Oven Trips Breaker When Bake Element Screwed To Back of Oven

Tags: oven, range

If I unscrew the bake element from the back of the stove so that the metal plate on the bake element (almost identical to this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Certified-Appliance-Accessories-Replacement-Oven-Bake-Element-for-GE-and-Hotpoint-WB44K10005/5001581763) does not touch the back of the stove it works fine and does not trip the breaker.

However, if that metal plate touches the back of the stove it trips the breaker if we try and use the bake function.

Model: GE J BP23D R3WW
Bake Element is: WB44T10060

This is where the element screws into the oven:
[image]
I'm reusing the same screws with the new element.

Any idea where to start?

Edit: I double checked the screws in the back of the oven and can confirm that the screws are not coming into contact with anything other than the insulation:
[image]

Note: I know my black and red are swapped (i.e. source red does not match oven red), I was doing testing

Comment: The exact brand/model of your stove (not just a link to one "almost identical") would be useful. In general, though, it sounds like there is some sort of insulating material missing somewhere and that screwing the element in all the way is causing a short. Consider taking a look at the back side of whatever part you're screwing the element into - it sounds like either you're not using OEM screws and they're too long, or that something has shifted and the screws are now hitting metal where they shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, should have known better and should have posted model.
Model: GE J BP23D R3WW
Bake Element is: WB44T10060

I know it's not the bake element itself since I actually purchased a replacement from searsdirect and the brand new element is doing the same thing.

I will check the screws.

Comment: Examine the heating element  to make sure it's not starting to break down around that metal plate.  If it is, screwing it into the grounded oven would cause a short.

Comment: I don't think it's the bake element since the brand new replacement bake element is doing the same thing.

I'm using the same screws that I believe came with the oven: https://imgur.com/a/QryMslw

Comment: @Kyle information about the model number and about the part number does not belong in comments ... please add it to the question ... this site is not a forum

Comment: `Any idea where to start?` ... yes, check the back of the oven ... something may be touching when the screws are in place

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button? What was the original motivation for changing the element?

Comment: Yes the breaker does have a TEST button and it works. 

The original motivation was replacing all knob and tube electrical. So when replacing that we updated the old 40amp breaker and 8 or 10 gauge wire that didn't have grounding to a gfci 50amp breaker with 6.3 wire.

Is it possible that corrosion on the two screws that mount the bake element is causing the issue? Are you able to find replacement (I'm assuming they're special high temp screws) screws at the local hardware store such as Lowes?

Answer (score 1):

A breaker with a TEST button means it's a GFCI or AFCI device. Those can't be used
on a circuit where the Neutral (white, usually) wire is connected anywhere to ground.
It appears from your photo that the green equiment ground wire may be connected to
the neutral tab of the range wiring bar. You need to remove the green wire and connect it to the stove chassis - there will likely be a green screw nearby for exactly that purpose. Any connection to the stove chassis from the stove neutral wiring will cause those kind of breakers to trip.

Comment: I believe the ground is connected to the stove chassis, here's another photo: https://imgur.com/a/usYOsk3

I removed the ground strap as instructed on the back panel of the stove:
https://imgur.com/a/SjDvolB

Comment: I don't know why someone upvoted this? I added a photo above to show more clearly that the incoming ground is connected to the stove chassis and not the range wiring bar.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it worked as it was connected. It appears you have a shorted element. IE. the resistance element is touching the case. This can be checked with an ohm meter. Power must be off before proceeding. Remove the wires from the element power terminals. Measure resistance between terminals and ground, you should not get a reading, if so you have a bad element. If you get no reading measure between both element terminals and if you get no reading you probably have your meter set incorrectly.

Comment: I don't think it's the bake element because I got a brand new replacement bake element and the brand new one does the same thing.